# Windows 10 reboots instead of going to sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, reboot, xeon

During the last week, my Win10 machine started to work weirdly. I've two main issues:

1. When I open the start menu, and click to Sleep in Power, the OS
   restarts (the Shut down and Restart options work properly).
2. When the screen turns off (instead of screen
   saver, I turn the screen off after 10mins), it signs out and signs
   in automatically. I don't have it set that it should ask for
   password, and is does not simply just locks the machine (Win+L) but
   closes all my programs as well.

What I've done:
I've the latest Win10 updates

The latest BIOS: version A20 - It says: "Update to the latest CPU microcode to address CVE-2017-5715 and associated Intel Reboot issue."

My machine is a Dell Precision T1600

- CPU: Intel Xeon E1270 @ 3.40GHz
- RAM: 16GB
- GPU: nVidia Quadro K2000
- SSD: OEM, 256GB (some LITE-on)
- HDD: WDC WD10EZEX 1TB

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific guideline for this procedure outlined by Dell. Please see it by navigating to [this link](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln308587/microprocessor-side-channel-vulnerabilities-cve-2017-5715-cve-2017-5753-cve-2017-5754-impact-on-dell-products?lang=en).

All the steps given by this link must be followed in order to mitigate any adverse effects. Be sure to restore power plans once you complete (advanced power plans).

If you want to further assess the problem, see what type of components trigger the logout action etc. you can always look into the event logs using Event Viewer. [This is a quick tutorial on the event viewer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938674.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking in the Windows Event Viewer for the Event ID "6006" which corresponds with the time your computer is shutting down due to this issue.

If you look at the event IDs leading up to that 6006, it should give you some clue as to what is causing the shutdown. If it's firmware, you'll likely see text about that in the event descriptions.

Answer (score -1):

Check in the bios options that the machine is not set to power back on on WOL, pci, usb or other inputs